# Iterate and getStdRandom

Tags: haskell, random

I have the following code (trying to simulate a Gaussian random walk):

```
import System.Random
import Control.Applicative

getStdNormal :: StdGen -> (Float,StdGen)
getStdNormal g = let l = drop 1 . take 49 $ iterate (\(_,g') -> random g') (0,g) in
                ((/ 2) . (+ (-24)) . sum . map fst $ l, snd . last $ l)

mphi = getStdRandom getStdNormal

l1 = setStdGen (mkStdGen 20180916) >> (sequence . take 10 $
                iterate (\s -> (\a -> \b ->  b) <$> s <*> mphi) (return 0))

l2 = setStdGen (mkStdGen 20180916) >> (sequence . take 10 $
                iterate (\s -> (\a -> \b -> a + b) <$> s <*> mphi) (return 0))
```

`l1` is evaluated to the list of (apparently normal) random values, just as I can expect:

```
[0.0,1.1155739,-0.24667645,0.7793722,-0.18391132,0.23517609,-0.80208874,-1.5305595,-0.28670216,0.53894806]
```

However, `l2` behaves far from my expectations. The list obviously is not the series of `l1` partial sums, and is very unlikely to have standard normal differences:

```
[0.0,1.1155739,0.55951977,0.22015285,-2.0858078,0.6170025,-5.20298,0.3877325,1.410594,0.8647003]
```

(Yet note that the first two members are correct.) In fact, I can't explain where do the numbers in `l2` come from, although I tend to blame laziness in `mphi`.

Why doesn't the code work as intended? Many thanks!

Comment: You should avoid `setStdGen` and `getStdRandom`.  You should just pass a `StdGen` value around, instead of  manipulating a global in IO. It makes it easier to compose values together.  And since the problem is likely the order of interleaved IO, avoiding it entirely should make everything easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the first few elements of `iterate (\s -> (\a b -> b) <$> s <*> mphi) (return 0)`:

```
return 0
(\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi
(\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi) <*> mphi
(\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi) <*> mphi) <*> mphi
```

When you sequence these, here's what you get:

```
do
    v0 <- return 0
    v1 <- (\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi
    v2 <- (\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi) <*> mphi
    v3 <- (\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> ((\a b -> b) <$> return 0 <*> mphi) <*> mphi) <*> mphi
    return [v0, v1, v2, v3]
```

Notice in particular that the random seed is not reset between these lines, and the things being thrown away by `\a b -> b` are *result values*, not *`IO` actions*. This means that we are getting the constant `0` in `v0`; the first element of the random sequence in `v1` (not `v0`!); the third element of the random sequence (completely skipping the second element) in `v2` (this one is probably what you wanted, but just by accident...); the sixth element of the random sequence in `v3` (not `v5`! and skipping the fourth and fifth elements of the sequence entirely); and so on up the triangle numbers, throwing away *most* of the random numbers we generate.

What you almost certainly wanted instead was

```
do
    v0 <- mphi
    v1 <- mphi
    v2 <- mphi
    v3 <- mphi
    return [v0, v1, v2, v3]
```

which can be achieved by using `repeat mphi` instead of `iterate (\s -> ...) (return 0)`. This lands us at:

```
sequence . take 10 $ repeat mphi
```

Idiomatically, one would then change `take 10 (repeat mphi)` to `replicate 10 mphi`, then change `sequence (replicate 10 mphi)` to `replicateM 10 mphi`.

Similar comments apply to your summing version: element `n` of the resulting list has generated `n` random numbers (distinct from any of the previously used ones for sums earlier in the result list) and summed them. Maybe this is what you want, but I suspect what you really wanted was just:

```
scanl (+) 0 <$> replicateM 10 mphi
```

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel! I still don't understand what's wrong with an _infinite_ list of randoms instead of `replicateM 10 mphi`. My naive code: `setStdGen (mkStdGen 20180916) >> (sequence . take 10 $ (scanl (\b -> \a -> (+) <$> b <*> a) (return 0) $ repeat mphi))` produces exactly the same incorrect result as `l2`does via `iterate`.

Comment: @rpns If you can explain which part of the first few paragraphs is not clear, I can try to refine it some. As it stands, the explanation for why the naive code you posted in your comment doesn't work is essentially the same as why your original `l1` and `l2` don't behave correctly.

Comment: If so, is there any simple way to generate an **infinite** list of partial sums of randoms like `scanl (+) 0 [1..]` for a pure series? Thank you!

Comment: @rpns You can look at `randomRs`. But it is much harder to use correctly than you might first guess: you must not reuse the seed you pass to it, and you don't get an updated seed back from it.